# Angular - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Angular 4.3.1
Angular CLI 1.2.3
Typescript 2.3.4

Component Typescript file:

```
public saveName: string;
public overwrite: boolean;
```

The following markup fails with **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'** when I run `ng build --prod`

```
<span>{{!overwrite || saveName}}</span>

OR

<button *ngIf="!overwrite && saveName">Save</button>
```

However, it works fine with the following:

```
<span>{{saveName || !overwrite}}</span>
<span>{{overwrite || saveName}}</span>
<button *ngIf="saveName && !overwrite">Save</button>
<button *ngIf="overwrite && saveName">Save</button>
```

Why am I getting that error?
More specifically, why does that error only show up when I have a negated boolean come before a string?

Answer (score 16):

Try `*ngIf="!overwrite && !!saveName"` to cast `saveName` to a boolean

The reason TypeScript gives for the error is roughly: you are using a string where you should be using a boolean.

The reason I think that it only happens in that circumstance is because if you have `true || anything` only the first will be evaluated (because if the first is true the whole expression will true regardless of the rest)