# Typescript - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have following typescript code:

```js
const parentItem= this.links.find((link) => {
  return urlArr.find((urlWord) => {
    return !!(urlWord === link.route.split('./')[1])
  })
});

// link.route.split('./')[1] is a string
// urlWord is also a string
// urlArr is array of strings
// links is an array of objects
```

and typescript keeps on complaining:

> .component.ts(11,59): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

The code works fine in chrome console.

This may look like similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246638/angular-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-boolean) but even after reading it I couldn't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Try .any instead of .find

Comment: Hi, I expanded your code (functionally identical) so it was easier to read. Hope that's ok

Comment: There is no such error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8IEsB2BrAzgLnhwBcZMBzAbQF0AaeAVxggEEYYDjSNLb4YB7ekRAcS5AFDiw-DMXgAHWCAxEAksIC28ALypMuAHQAzTMAAU6bDoB8DJqxjHTZxhADq-GMBt33n79qBfILCBjjy6ERmAOQGAPTRAJQUAIxUiYkA3EA

Comment: You should ensure `parentItem` is receives a string: `const parentItem: string = ...`. It may be worth actually adding expected types throughout your code as you'll get a more helpful error much closer to the actual issue. It's hard to tell what's going on here because none of us know what actual types have been laid out in the system. Typescript is about making less assumptions. You're asking us to make a bunch of assumptions here.

Comment: ^That won't do anything. @sttaq Do you have more code to show? What is `this.links`?

Comment: @JLF, seems like in his definition of `find` the `predicate` should return `boolean` instead of `unknown`.

Comment: @Qwertiy that's gotta be it. `Array.prototype.find()` for a string array returns a string (or undefined). The `find` predicate must return a boolean so using the nested `urlArr.find()` as the return value for the `links.find` predicate is invalid

Comment: `find()` expects a function that returns a `boolean` and itself returns a `string`. Thus the inner `find()` returns a `string`, and therefore the function passed to the outer `find()` returns a string, and not a `boolean` as expected. The Chrome console will regard the string as truthy, TypeScript however will complain.

Comment: @mwilson `this.links` is an array of objects and when run in chrome the `parentItem` is set to one of those object.

Comment: @JLF, the code comments have all the types mentioned. Is there something else you need to know about the types?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The inner find returns a string which is returned as a result for outer find. I needed to ensure that the string returned by inner find as considered as truthy as chrome does it.

Comment: @ChrisG, check actual typing. There is no `boolean` in `find`s `predicate`.

Comment: @Zacharious means `urlArr.some()` and not `urlArr.any()` There's no such thing as `.any()`. But they're right. `.some()` is a great idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I need to return a boolean in the find function. So doing the following ensure that the result of inner find is converted to a boolean.

```
const parentItem= this.links.find((link) => {
  // convert to boolean
  return !!(urlArr.find((urlWord) => {
    return urlWord === link.route.split('./')[1]
  }));
});
```

The code above now returns a matched link object or undefined.

Comment: You should check out `Array.prototype.some()` as indicated in [Qwertiy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313086/283366)

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: "typescript": "~3.2.2",

Answer (score 2):

Just update your typescript and/or typings. There is [no any error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8IEsB2BrAzgLngG94YB7AVwBcQCdKZMBzeAXwG0BdAKFElgWQx45GBACCMGLXpNOXLmFIY68AA78MlAJLUAtvAC8qTLgB0AM0zAAFOmyGAfMNESYFq9ZEQA6qRjBHZx8-AIMw42xTMioQUxxVdEprAHJTAHpkgEo2AEYOTMyAbiA) in your code

```
declare var links: { route: string }[]
declare var urlArr: string[]

const parentItem = links.find(link => urlArr.find(urlWord => urlWord === link.route.split('./')[1]));
```

as in current version of typescript defines `find` method as

```
(method) Array<string>.find(predicate: (value: string, index: number, obj: string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): string | undefined (+1 overload)
```

note `unknown` instead of `boolean` - you may return anything you want.

But as you actually don't need result of inner `find` (unless you can find an empty string), you can use `some` instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Facing with same issue by html  control disabled="disabled" changed to **[disabled]="true"** and problem was solved.